# can you show the solution for this in finding the value of a?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{a^2+4^2-5^2}{8a} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{a^2+4^2-6^2}{8a}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1- \Big(\frac{a^2+4^2-6^2}{8a}\Big)^2}$$

show the solution in finding the  value of A

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you tried to get rid of the square root?

Comment: I suppose you mean $a$ (lowercase), as there is no $A$ in the equation. Anyhow, have you tried isolating the square root on one side, then squaring the equation? You should now get a polynomial equation (after multiplying by $a^2$). It will have too high a degree to get further, unless you're lucky. (And if this comes from a textbook, it may have been rigged so that you will be lucky.)

Comment: Is the LHS $5^2$ or $6^2$? If $6^2$, then let $x=\frac{a^2+4^2-6^2}{8a}$. You will get $$(2-\sqrt{3})x=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$Squaring both sides

Comment: if the question is typed correctly, try substituting $a^2+4^2=B$ and then proceed, notice that under the $\sqrt{...}$ if you make ${8a}^2$ as common denominator, it gets cancelled from LHS and RHS

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{a^2 + 4^2 - 6^2}{8a}.$$

Then we have:

$$\sin(\theta) + \frac{11}{8a} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(\theta) + \frac{1}{2}\cos(\theta).$$

Simplifying, we have:

$$\sin(\theta) + \frac{11}{8a} = \sin\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{6}\right).$$

Consequently:

$$\sin\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{6}\right) - \sin(\theta) = \frac{11}{8a}.$$

Simplifying the left-hand side of the last equation, we get:

$$\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}\cos\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{12}\right) = \frac{11}{8a}.$$

Therefore:

$$\cos\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{12}\right) = \frac{11\left(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}\right)}{8a}.$$

Hence:

$$\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{11\left(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}\right)}{8a}\right) - \frac{\pi}{12}.$$

Now plug $\theta$ into:

$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{a^2 - 20}{8a},$$

and then solve for $a$.

Using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28arccos%2811sqrt%282+%2B+sqrt%283%29%29%2F8x%29+-+%28pi%2F12%29%29+%3D+%28%28x%5E2+-+20%29%2F%288x%29%29),

$$a \approx -0.798038 + 0.540401i,$$

or

$$a \approx -0.798038 - 0.540401i.$$